# Cannot change to English UK from English US

Tags: languages

I recently updated my HTC Desire S to ICS 4.04 and sense 4.6 via the upgrade available at HTCDEV.COM

Since then my default language is English US and cannot change it to English UK via the setting>Language and Keyboard

It also changed my contact number from 12345677 to 123-45-67 which i am quessing it has to do with the US locale?
Thanks

Comment: Did you download the correct ROM? http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads shows ROM for different carriers and country.

Comment: There's only 2 versions  one for chineese and the WWE,,i downloaded the WWE one....i am base din cyprus which is EU.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem. Try downloading Custom Locale from the Play Store and you can select your language. Do a reboot once you have changed the settings in the app and it will have reflected it in the device settings.

Comment: am quessing the app needs to be running in the backround for the local to remain throughout?